# MySQL query is slow if we pass variable in where condition

Tags: mysql

**This is slow and taking 1.003 seconds**

```
set @POSTCODE = 'SL2 1AT';
select latitude, longitude from postcode.postcodelatlng where postcode = @POSTCODE;
```

**This is fast and taking .127 seconds**

```
select latitude, longitude from postcode.postcodelatlng where postcode = 'SL2 1AT';
```

**Table create statement**

```
CREATE TABLE `postcodelatlng` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `postcode` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(18,15) NOT NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(18,15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_postcode` (`postcode`),
  KEY `latLong` (`latitude`,`longitude`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1738245 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Could you please help, why this is happening and we can we do to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, I suggest you use InnoDB over MyISAM.
The compare to a latin1 field was incurring a fairly heavy performance overhead.
instead of you can use following.

```
SET @POSTCODE:= CONVERT('SL2 1AT' USING latin1);
```

If you client is utf8 but your table is latin1.Now the query runs as fast as I would expect.

Comment: Hi Ankit, Thanks for your reply. This table is read only there is no insert update happening, so I am using MyISAM engine for this table. There are only 18Lakh records in this table. Let me try other points that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

`:=` is [the assignment operator in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/assignment-operators.html)

```
set @POSTCODE := 'SL2 1AT';
select latitude, longitude from postcode.postcodelatlng where postcode = @POSTCODE;
```

There is a colon missing in the first line